# Getting Facebook permissions in Google Action

Tags: node.js, nlp, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am currently building a Google Assistant App/ Action using API.AI and node.js. My application needs to get permissions from the user, to get his Facebook likes and make FB Graph API calls from node.js. How can I do that? Do I need to build an android/ ios app for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to implement account linking. However, you will not be able to use the Facebook OAuth directly but have to implement your own OAuth server. Your service will independently need to get the user to provide the Facebook OAuth credentials so you can use their API.